# Can't update OS

Tags: release-jolnir, update-manager

It's been a while, and I think I need some guidance if anyone can offer it. For the past few days i've tried to update my operating system, and I get this message:

> "Failed to update Operating System updates This may have been caused
> by external or manually compiled software.
>
> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a'
> to correct the problem."

Not sure what is going on here. I have done updates to the OS with no problem recently, so I'm not sure what's holding up this particular update.

One more thing: I keep getting notifications from a website that I've not subscribed to or read. The site is called Patheos. I'm not sure where to look to stop these notifications. Any advice for this as well? I'm using Firefox if that helps or means anything. Never had notifications pop up before. All of a sudden I'm getting notifications from this site. I think there may be something in Firefox that needs to be changed, but I don't seem to be able to find it.

Comment: This is an uncommon error to receive. Could you [edit] your question to show the full output of `sudo apt update`? This may point to which package(s) to address 